# Turn off layout for one of action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

My situation:
View action of ReportsController should render pure html, but not as a file (to view it in browser and save it after). So for rendering I use view template view.html.erb and i neet to turn off any layouts for this action. But in other actions of this controller layouts should stay untouched.
Works only turning off for whole controller like this:

```
ReportsController < ApplicationController
  layout false
```

But that doing it wrong :( for all the actions
I tried to use something like this in action:

```
def view      
  @report = Report.new(params[:report])
  unless @report.valid?
    render :action => 'new' and return
  else
    render :layout => false     
  end   
end
```

What should I do?

Comment: Well, you definitely don't need that explicit return.  Do you want the layout to render if the report is valid?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this:

```
ReportsController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  layout 'application', :except => :view
```

Comment: It seems like this directive works wrong (or unexpected). I tried to use some combinations of these parameters (:only, :except). But it worked strange removing all the layouts for all the actions. I think it's because of nil or false instead of 'layoutname'. And system tries to use 'controllername' layouts for all the other actions ignoring application layout. Try to play with this parameters and you'll understand what this all about.

Comment: You're right, `:only` doesn't work properly on `layout nil`. I was able to get it working by nilling the layout and adding it back with the exception, however. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Answer by David Ortiz is "more correct," as it properly isolates the layout switch to the lone action in question.

Comment: I agree with @Paul - `false` works! Thanks for that!

Comment: `layout false, only: :view` feels like a more concise way to accomplish the same goal without side effects like Antiarchitect mentions.

Answer (score 123):

This should do it,

```
def view
    ...
    render :layout => false
end
```

[Link to Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option)

Comment: The problem with this is you'd have to specify `layout: false` for every format in the action.

Answer (score 12):

In the respond block, add `layout: false`.

For example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => false }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a non-standard template, with no layout you can use:

```
def non_rest
  render template: 'layouts/something_new', layout: false
end
```

Comment: How about the opposite - can I render the default layout with no template?