# Ruby on Rails - How do I render an action without the application layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and I want to render an action without using my application layout (which has page header / footer stuff in it).

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50491420/3757435

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Here's some documentation about it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

For your question:

```
render :layout => false
```

or

```
layout false
```

Comment: Keep in mind `layout nil` will disable all layouts for that controller. And `layout nil, :only => [:action]` will also remove the layout for the controller (currently a bug).

Comment: layout false did not work for me, but render :layout => false does.

Comment: This is really useful for rendering e.g. CSV templates.

Answer (score 5):

For Rails 5, in the controller, for the specific action:

```rb
def action
  render layout: false
end
```