# Restrict access to the whole website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am new on Rails and I have a website where users can post article but this website will be accessible only for the people who logged in and I have several questions.

First, how can I do to create a page without the application layout because I just want a form in the "Log in" page ?

How can I restrict the access for the users who didn't logged in and redirect them to the Log in page ?

**EDIT** : for my first question, here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840926/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-render-an-action-without-the-application-layout)

Comment: are you using devise for authentication?

Comment: No, I did it from scratch

Comment: use **devise** gem for authentication

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840926/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-render-an-action-without-the-application-layout

Comment: I have edited my question and I redirect to this link :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this path:

1. Build authentication from scratch to understand how it works. There is a good tutorial here http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised
2. When you understand principles of authentication, you can use [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/Devise) or [Sorcery gem](https://github.com/noamb/sorcery).
3. Managing the level of restrictions for different users can be accomplished easily with [CanCanCan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

Comment: My authentication is already working, I followed the railcast tuto
But, for some reason I can't use Devise gem, Can i use CanCan gem without Devise ?

Comment: CanCan is authorization gem. You need authentication logic. Why can't you use Devise or Sorcery?