# ruby on rails how to render a page without layout and other head field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

```
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "tabelle/show" }
  end
end
```

I want to render the page ...with only the code in that page....not add `<head>`...layout and `<body>` field in ruby on rails.
I only want to show the result of code in the page tabelle/show.html.haml

Comment: Could this solve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062312/turn-off-layout-for-one-of-action?

Comment: see also - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
format.html { render "tabelle/show", :layout => false  }
```

Comment: You can also do this controller wide by calling `layout false` on the controller:

    class FooController < ApplicationController;
      layout false;
    end

Comment: @MartinSvalin You can indeed do that, but that affects all the actions within the `FooController`, it seems the OP have a more localised need for controlling the layout.

Comment: Can you render without specifying the view to use, like `render layout: false` and it will use the `show.html.erb` in the `tabelle` directory automatically but without the typical layout?

Comment: Turns out you can!

Answer (score 13):

Controller:

```
layout false, only: [:method_name]
```

this is very useful when you using render_to_string

Answer (score 9):

add

```
:layout => false
```

Example:

```
render "tabelle/show", :layout => false
```

Comment: What if i render a partial,and i want to show the layout...i render it directly from the controller, i do 'render partial:'successful_download', locals:{link:@gig.boxlink}' and it does work,but the layout disappears.How to make it appear?

Answer (score 9):

#### If you do not want to specify the view to use.

Rails is smart enough to know which view template to use based on the Controller Action you're on.

For example, if you're on the `show` action of the `TabellesController` you wouldn't need to specify `render "tabelle/show"` in your Controller Action because Rails will already assume that and will automatically try to render the file in `app/views/tabelles/show.html.erb`.

So if you're sticking with all of those defaults then you can just use the following to render *without* the typical layout template:

```
def show
  # Other stuff in your Controller Action.

  render layout: false
end
```

This will render `app/views/tabelles/show.html.erb` but without the layout template automatically.

Noice.