# Modal loading the header and footer instead of the just the attended page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use http://jquerymodal.com/ for a simple sign in modal. But for some reason clicking the link_to the modal. open up another view of the application html. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Highlighted in blue there is the only thing that should be displayed but for some reason the entire application is being rendered... Here is my HTML for the page I want to render:

```
<div id="modal">
  <h2>Sign In</h2>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-input", autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-input", autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password" %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
    <% end -%>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

### MODAL OPEN

```
<%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, class: "button", rel: "modal:open" %>
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <div id="ex1" style="display:none;">
    <p>modal text........<a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
   </div>

   <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
```

Comment: @Bitwise If you share the place where your clicking for open modal then I will change answer accordingly.

Comment: @Bitwise Is your "jquery.modal.js" is loading on the page? 
You are redirecting your page with "new_user_session_path". Please, use as :
<%= link_to "Sign In", "#modal", class: "button", rel: "modal:open" %>

When modal will be open you can do any action on button submit.

Hope this solution will help you!

Comment: Now it doesn't open the page?

Comment: I appreciate the help but that's not what I was looking for. But you are right!

Comment: @Bitwise happy to hear! what about upvote! :) If possible not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking

```
<div ID="Modal"></div>
```

Outside the container div. Because it is inheriting Box-size of it's parent element which is `Container`. And Another thing to note is that you'll be calling only modal ID through JQuery so Container Element's styling should not be inherited in modal element. So I think problem is that only.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the *modal open* is going back to the server to fetch the code to render (on `new_user_session_path`) ?

This will be re-rendering your layout `application.html.erb`, which is why you are seeing the header and footer also appear.

The solution here is to turn off the layout in your `user_sessions` controller, or (if you're rendering to an `iframe` for example) replace it with a secondary layout e.g. `application_modal.html.erb` that doesn't do anything but set up the stylesheets.

You can find more info on working with layouts in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062312/turn-off-layout-for-one-of-action).